# How to calculate Sin function quicker and more precisely?

Tags: c++, algorithms

I want to calculate `y(n)=32677Sin(45/1024•n)`, where `y` is an integer and `n` ranges from 0 to 2048. How can I make this process quicker and more precisely? 
   Now I want to show you a reference answer:
   Since   `Sin(a+b)=Sin(a)Cos(b)+Cos(a)Sin(b)` 
   And  `Cos(a+b)=Cos(a)Cos(b)-Sin(a)Cos(b)`.
   So I can store  `Sin(45/1024•1)` and  `Cos(45/1024•1)` only.Then use this formula:

`Sin(45/1024•2)=Sin(45/1024•1+45/1024•1)`, 
    `Cos(45/1024•2)=Cos(45/1024•1+45/1024•1)`,
  `Sin(45/1024•n)=Sin(45/1024•(n-1)+45/1024•1)`, 
    `Cos(45/1024•n)=Cos(45/1024•(n-1)+45/1024•1)` ,
This way maybe quicker without storing large array.

Comment: This question is appropriate for Programmers, assuming the intention is to learn about the appropriate algorithms and/or data structures from the perspective of software engineering concerns.

Comment: That 45 is a bit suspect; it makes me think you want `sin(x)` where `x` is in degrees. If that's the case, you need to be aware that the argument to the trig functions is typically in radians. The argument is in radians in C++, which is how this question is tagged.

Comment: Why do you need this question answered?  What's the application?

Comment: How accurate do you need the result to be?

Comment: @dan04 Since y is an integer, I need it accurate as an integer .

Comment: I don't understand the reason you think your idea would be any faster then reference answer.  You are doing exactly the samething, the processing time, is exactly the same.  Furthermore what makes calculating sin and cos slow still exists in your solution.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you really don't understand me. This reference solution only requires you to store Sin(45/1024) and Cos(45/1024). Then calculates the following result without calculating any sin and cos!!

Answer (score 18):

If `n` ranges from 0 to 2048, you can pre-calculate the values, store then in an array. `y(n)` would become `values[n]`.

Comment: +1 and you can interpolate for any values in between (if that's a possibility).

Comment: That's a viable option, though I'd still profile it to make sure it is more efficient than calculating it (e.g. the FPU's `fsin` might be used and be more cache-friendly than some array).

Comment: How about not storing value[n]?

Comment: Trigonometric functions are very slow to compute on the fly.  I'm pretty sure every fast implementation uses pre-computed values.  Since sin() and cos() are periodic, you only need to store the first 90 degrees.  You can return -sin(), or sin(90 - the angle), or -sin(90 - the angle) depending on the quadrant.  You can also define cos() in terms of sin().  If you know the possible range of input values, you can pre-compute and only store the values you need for your program.  If not, interpolation between a limited number of values may be your fastest option.

Comment: @user1297181 re: not storing value[n].  You have a trade off - cpu time vs memory.  If the native implementation of `sin(x)` is too slow to call and compute, the fastest way to get the data would be to look it up in a precomputed table.  You may be able to shrink the size of the table if you are able to identify the period of the data.

Comment: @GlenPeterson: What happens if the standard libraries already do this?

Comment: @Loki Astari: Not sure what you are getting at.  I would absolutely use the standard libraries if at all practical.  Presumably they have somehow fallen short of user1297181's needs or he/she is implementing a new language with new libraries or cannot use the existing ones for some reason (e.g. accuracy, speed, or size).

Comment: P.S. I don't think vartec is suggesting that you just pre-compute the sins, rather that you make a table that takes n as an index and returns `32677 * Sin(45/1024 * n)`.  I think you need a 32-bit int because 32,677 is dangerously close to 32,767 (probably a typo actually) which is the max value for a 16-bit int.  Unless you want it to wrap for some reason...

Comment: @Glen: Sin values are between -1 and 1, so it will actually fit in 16-bit unsigned.

Comment: @vartec: Oops - thanks!  Yes, then it must be 32,767, not 32,677.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the table at compile time instead of run time.

You're doing a 2048-element table of 16-bit scaled integer values.

Write a cheap Matlab script, with a print that gives a data line suitable for your final programming language.  Cut-and-paste the result into your source code, as a constant data table, and do a table lookup at run time.  This pushes the initial computation time off into the build cycle, instead of the program startup time.

Comment: How much runtime does this save compared to the extra programmer cost?

Comment: Quick and dirty. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Given the form of the function, the natural answer is [the CORDIC algorithm](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~jhw/cordic/index.html). It's a much cleaner approach than the breakdown in the question. On the other hand, the table it needs is far, far smaller than the table others have suggested.